# When entering in UITextfield scrollview goes down in iPhone4S

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, size-classes

I have an issues with textfield, with iPhone4S Only. I was taken some textfield and and write following method for UITextFields

```
    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    if(textField==txtAmount){
        [txtAmount resignFirstResponder];
        [txtVat becomeFirstResponder];
        if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
            [scrollObj setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 155) animated:YES];
        }
        else if (IS_IPHONE_6){
            [scrollObj setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 150) animated:YES];
        }
        else if (IS_IPHONE_6P){
            [scrollObj setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 150) animated:YES];
        }
        else{
            [scrollObj setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,250) animated:YES];
        }
    }
    else if (textField==txtVat) {
        [txtVat resignFirstResponder];
        [txtShope becomeFirstResponder];

        if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
            [scrollObj setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 212) animated:YES];
        }
        else if (IS_IPHONE_6){
            [scrollObj setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 210) animated:YES];
        }
        else if (IS_IPHONE_6P){
             [scrollObj setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 205) animated:YES];
        }
        else{
           [scrollObj setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 330) animated:YES];
        }
    }
    else if (textField==txtShope) {
        [txtShope resignFirstResponder];
        [txtProductName becomeFirstResponder];

        if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
            [scrollObj setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 295) animated:YES];
        }
        else if (IS_IPHONE_6){
            [scrollObj setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 295) animated:YES];
        }
        else if (IS_IPHONE_6P){
            [scrollObj setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 290) animated:YES];
        }
        else{
            [scrollObj setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 400) animated:YES];
        }
    }
    else{
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [scrollObj setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
    }
    return YES;
}


-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField==txtAmount) {
        if (IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS) {
            [scrollObj setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 65) animated:YES];
        }
    }
    else if (textField==txtVat ) {
        if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
            [scrollObj setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 155) animated:YES];
        }
        else if (IS_IPHONE_6){
            [scrollObj setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 150) animated:YES];
        }
        else if (IS_IPHONE_6P){
            [scrollObj setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 150) animated:YES];
        }
        else{
            [scrollObj setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 450) animated:YES];
        }
    }
    else if (textField==txtShope){
        if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
            [scrollObj setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 212) animated:YES];
        }
        else if (IS_IPHONE_6){
            [scrollObj setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 210) animated:YES];
        }
        else if (IS_IPHONE_6P){
            [scrollObj setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 205) animated:YES];
        }
        else{
            [scrollObj setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 650) animated:YES];
        }
    }
    else if (textField==txtProductName){
        if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
            [scrollObj setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 295) animated:YES];
        }
        else if (IS_IPHONE_6){
            [scrollObj setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 295) animated:YES];
        }
        else if (IS_IPHONE_6P){
            [scrollObj setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 290) animated:YES];
        }
        else{
            [scrollObj setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 400) animated:YES];
        }

    }
}
```

it's perfectly work in iPhone5, iPhone6, iPhone6P but not working in iPhone4S 
When click on txtAmount it Fist behave right, it sets its contentofset perfect and then suddenly goes down scrollview. I can't find out the solution.

```
if (textField==txtAmount) {
        if (IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS) {
            [scrollObj setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 65) animated:YES];
        }
    }
```

Above code set the content of set of scrollview but after that it goes down. can any one help me? its working on Other devices but not on iPhone4s. I used Sizeclass and Autoresize in XIB. And I was not set contentofset of scrollview in any other methods.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The scrollview content calculations should be same for both textFieldShouldReturn and textFieldDidBeginEditing delegates. I advise you to create a method that handle the content operations and then you can call it from related delegates. Otherwise you will face many problems.

Comment: @ondermerol thanks for your reply, but I didn't get you. can you elebrate it?

Comment: I think it is better that managing scrollview contentoffset and other related properties (contentsize, vs.) in a single method. I could not understand why you have different contentoffset management in those delegates. I just want to help you to answer your own question, I don't have an answer, sorry. But it seems that the problem exists for iphone 4s because the contentsize is bigger than the screensize/view (for iphoe 5+ it is opposite I think).